# how to get the bitmap from cusom imageview class?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-custom-view

i want the get the whole bimap map of custom class... i getting the null...i try to every way i don't getting the write answer..

`Bitmap b = mBoardTile.getDrawing();` i used it but get the null value..

i m also used view cache like..

```
      Bitmap b = null;
    try {
        mBoardTile.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        mBoardTile.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        mBoardTile.layout(0, 0, mBoardTile.getMeasuredWidth(), mBoardTile.getMeasuredHeight());
        mBoardTile.buildDrawingCache(true);
        b = mBoardTile.getDrawingCache();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`
```

but again get the null value..

the custom class is below..

```
public class BoardTile extends ImageView {
 Context mContext;
 int posx, posy;
 ArrayList<Datavo> mArrayListDta;

float width, height, newx, newy;
ArrayList<Datavo> mArrayListNew;

public BoardTile(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.mContext = context;
    mArrayListNew = new ArrayList<Datavo>();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mArrayListNew.size(); i++) {
        Datavo mDatavo = mArrayListNew.get(i);

                Bitmap mOriginalBitmap = mDatavo.getmBitmap();
                // Scale to target size
                mOriginalBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mOriginalBitmap, mDatavo.getWidth_new(), mDatavo.getHeight_new()/2, true);

   //                   Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(mOriginalBitmap);
                canvas.drawBitmap(mOriginalBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

}

public void getData(ArrayList<Datavo> mArrayList) {

    this.mArrayListDta = mArrayList;
    for (int i = 0; i < mArrayListDta.size(); i++) {

        newx = 480 * mArrayListDta.get(i).getxCordi() / mArrayListDta.get(i).getWidth();
        newy = 800 * mArrayListDta.get(i).getyCordi() / mArrayListDta.get(i).getHeight();

        width = newx * mArrayListDta.get(i).getWidth() / mArrayListDta.get(i).getxCordi();
        height = newy * mArrayListDta.get(i).getHeight() / mArrayListDta.get(i).getyCordi();

        Datavo mDatavo = new Datavo();
        mDatavo.setxCordi_new((int) newx);
        mDatavo.setyCordi_new((int) newy);
        mDatavo.setWidth_new((int) width);
        mDatavo.setHeight_new((int) height);
        mDatavo.setmBitmap(mArrayListDta.get(i).getmBitmap());
        mArrayListNew.add(mDatavo);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing it in onDraw method it will call multiple times..

Comment: @kalyanpvs i add the multiple imageview in getdata() arraylist.. so i need to for loop..

Comment: @kalyanpvs i just add the multiple imageview and all its drawn on canvas.. its draw prefect but not getting the custom class imageview bitmap..

Comment: Don't do heavy work in `onDraw()` callback. here `createScaledBitmap()` is an expensive work...

Comment: @GopalRao i knw that but not have the another way to all images bitmap with proper size..

Answer (score 0):

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable=(BitmapDrawable) _image_view.getDrawable();
bitmapDrawable.getBitmap()
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution for getting the whole bitmap from custom class....

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view

    int FixWidth = 480;
    int FixHeight = 800;
    int bit_width = 0;
    int bit_height = 0;

    bit_width = mImageViewBackgroud.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    bit_height = mImageViewBackgroud.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

    if (bit_width > FixWidth) {
        bit_width = FixWidth;
    }

    if (bit_height > FixHeight) {
        bit_height = FixHeight;
    }

    float ratio = Math.min((float) 800 / bit_width, (float) 800 / bit_height);
    int width = Math.round((float) ratio * bit_width);
    int height = Math.round((float) ratio * bit_height);

    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    //Bind a canvas to it
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    //Get the view's background
    Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null) 
        //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else 
        //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    // draw the view on the canvas
    view.draw(canvas);
    //return the bitmap
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

hope this code helps to others....